# Typescript control flow analysis doesn't recognise a known type

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to understand why the compiler needs to be explicitly told what the type of value in the `Policies` type is, even though it can only be one of my `Types`.

```
type Types = 'baz' | 'bar';

// tagged union types
type Foo<T extends Types> = { type: T; }
type FooOne = { one: string } & Foo<'baz'>;
type FooAnother = { another: string } & Foo<'bar'>;

type Predicate<T extends Types> = (e: Foo<T>) => boolean;

type Policies = {
    [P in Types]: Predicate<P>
}

const policies: Policies = {
    baz: (e: FooOne) => e.one === 'neo',
    bar: (e: FooAnother) => e.another === 'morphieus'
}

// this method receives a union type
function verify(e: FooOne | FooAnother) {
    // these both work, understandably
    if (e.type === 'baz') {
        const policy1 = policies[e.type]; // ide says this type is a Predicate<'baz'>
        const result1 = policy1(e); // fine  
    } else {
        const policy2 = policies[e.type]; // and this is a Predicate<'bar'>
        const result2 = policy2(e); // fine
    }

    // but this doesn't work even though e.type is known to be 'baz' | 'bar', and the keys at policies can only be 'baz' | 'bar'
    const policy3 = policies[e.type]; // ide says this type is a Predicate<'bar'> | Predicate<'baz'>
    const result3 = policy3(e); // error Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature  

    // this works, if i hint to the compiler what is at policies[T]
    const policy4: Predicate<Types> = policies[e.type]; // Predicate<'baz' | bar'>
    const result4 = policy4(e); // fine 
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that's just the way it is for now at least.  I don't think the [union signature fix](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/29011) will deal with these kinds of correlated types.  I've tried [suggesting a solution](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/25051) but it will probably not be implemented.  For now I'd say just assert your way out of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no good solution here, you will need some sort of type assertion to get things working.

The problem is that flow analysis does not keep track of where values come from. So when you write:

```
const policy3 = policies[e.type]; 
const result3 = policy3(e);
```

`policy3` will be `Predicate<"baz"> | Predicate<"bar">` but the compiler does not know which one. When you call `policy3` since it does not know which function type is actually in the variable, it will force you, in newer versions, to specify an argument that can work with either function in the union. It does not remember that `policy3` si actually tied to `e.type` and `policy3(e)` will be type safe. (FYI: in older versions `policy3` would not be callable at all since it is a union)

This code works:

```
const policy4= policies[e.type] as Predicate<Types> ; // Predicate<'baz' | bar'>
const result4 = policy4(e); // fine
```

But `Predicate<"baz"> | Predicate<"bar">` is not the same as `Predicate<Types>`. The former is a either a function that takes `baz` or a function that takes `bar` the latter is a function that takes either `baz` or `bar`. So the call will work because you have asserted the function can accept either parameter type (which is not strictly true but like I said no good solutions).

Comment: thanks for the detailed response. i guess i dont mind telling the compiler if it's not smart enough to know. but im more worried that there is something unsafe about what im doing. i cant really see any cases that would cause something to blow up at runtime

Comment: @AaronHS like  jcalz commented they could implement this but they just haven't (not that I'm blaming them, priorities...) It is safe.